# How could I programmatically trigger google analytics events without a browser?

Tags: java, google-analytics

Background:

We receive non web based events (like SMS) to our server, it would be nice to be able to track them via analytics.

I have thought of several solutions, but am not entirely happy with any of them.

1. Hack together the analytics url and post it using from the server.

   Unsure if this would work as there are a lot of unexplained variables in the URL
2. Use a Javascript library, such as Rhino to attempt to use the ga.js script without a web request.

   Once again, unsure if this will work, rhino doesn't appear to support Document which is required by the script.
3. I was thinking about firing events from the server to a page, but of course that would require the server to have a javascript engine.

Cheers

Jono

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe GA has a noscript option that relies on downloading a invisible image. Could you request that file from your non-web based events?

Comment: Here is a php script to call the image

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=60c76276a088c32a&hl=en

Answer (score 3):

Here is a java library that works very well.

https://code.google.com/p/jgoogleanalyticstracker/

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm 4 years late in answering this question, but I think Google released a helpful tool here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/

Comment: Is it possible to call http POST requests from java code? I cannot find any implementation details using that approach, ie authentication vs. Because we need to authorize or sth to post the event data via analytics.